# Random Colors with preference

Tags: javascript, random, rgb

The idea:
I am trying to simulate a shop system. By clicking on items the users shows that he is interested in stuff like that and gets more like it the next time he visits the website. I want to achieve something similar only without things to buy, but with colors. You get random colors. If you 'like' red colors you get random ones but more red than usual.

So far in theory.
Practically I made cookies for r,g and b with the starting values 1.0. Each time one of the colors is clicked the value rises +0.1 and the others go down -0.1.
But how can take the numbers into account?

This is my Javascript so far:

```
var r = getCookie("r");
var g = getCookie("g");
var b = getCookie("b");

if (r = ""){
    setCookie("r",1.0,365);
    setCookie("g",1.0,365);
    setCookie("b",1.0,365);
}
init();
function init(){


  var colorboxes =  document.getElementsByClassName("mycolorbox");

    [].forEach.call(colorboxes,function(entry){


        var sr = Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));
        var sg = Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));
        var sb = Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));

       entry.style.backgroundColor = "rgba("+sr+","+sg+","+sb+",0.8)";
    });

}



$(document).click(function(event) {
    var clickedObj = $(event.target);

    if (clickedObj[0].className.indexOf("likebox") > -1) {

        clickedObj[0].style.Color = "red";
        var rgb = clickedObj[0].parentNode.style.backgroundColor.match(/\d+/g);
        console.log(rgb);
        console.log(clickedObj[0].className);
        console.log("rot: "+rgb[0]+" gruen: "+rgb[1]+" blau: "+rgb[2]);

        if (rgb[0] >= rgb[1] && rgb[0] >= rgb[2]) {
            alert("red");
            setCookie("r",r-0.1,365)
        } else if (rgb[1] >= rgb[0] && rgb[1] >= rgb[2]) {
            alert("green");
            setCookie("g",g-0.1,365)
        } else if (rgb[2] >= rgb[1] && rgb[2] >= rgb[0]) {
            alert("blue");
            setCookie("b",b-0.1,365)
        }

    }
});

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Besides your question... `Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 255) + 255));` Are you sure this works? For me it looks like you multiply the random value with zero, so it would always result in a value of `0 + 255` = 255.

Comment: Ups my problem. It should be Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));

Comment: You're telling us you will subtract (-)0.1 on two values when 1 value increases with (+)0.1 ... This eventually will create negative values. So, make sure to check on the highest value and support negative values or fix it. I just couldn't help to notice :)

Comment: You are right. I will handle it after I got a solution.

Comment: Personally I don;t quite get your question. Maybe it's because my lack of knowledge or it's my view on it. Maybe you could specify `But how can take the numbers into account?` a bit more? It might also help if you provide us with the output of the log, then we know what kind of data we work with after each step :) (I'm not that good myself, maybe that's why I think it would help, I might not be able to finish your code, but maybe if I understand it better I could help thinking of a solution to tackle the problem.)

Comment: Okay. All I want is some way to manipulate the chances of appearence of a specific color (r,g,b). Something like:
`if r > b and r >g 
make more red tones 
and if g>b and g>r then
make more green tones`

The output is are just some divs that are colored differently. If you click on one the r,g,b values are compared and the highest one gets increast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if I got your problem right, but one approach might be to multiply the random values with the respective cookie values.

```js
// you already have this code for random numbers
var sr = Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));
var sg = Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));
var sb = Math.round((Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1));

// now let's multiply these values with the user's preferences
sr *= r;
sg *= g;
sb *= b;
```

To prevent overflows (and underflows), we have to make sure the values stay between `0` and `255`:

```js
sr = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, sr));
sg = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, sg));
sb = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, sb));
```

This is, of course, a very basic solution and does not deliver optimal results. I have not actually tried it out, but I guess it will get "better" after a few runs, just as intended.