# Limiting colors when using getRandomColor

Tags: javascript

I have setup a basic getRandomColor function in javascript but I am having trouble figuring out how to limit the color spectrum that it uses. I want it to be more White & Grey colors. Is this possible?

My code is as follows:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");
    var color = "#";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random Colors with preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731866/random-colors-with-preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to an online color picker like [this one](http://www.colorpicker.com), and look through a bunch of grey/white/black colors.  On the webpage I linked to, you can do this by clicking to the verrrry left of the color box.

Look and see if you can find a pattern in the ratio between red/blue/green in the colors you want.  Let me know if you find the pattern.

### Edit

Alright, I'll let the cat out of the bag like the other answer has already done.  When we have a 6-digit hex code, we have 2 digits for red, 2 digits for blue, and 2 digits for green.

```
        # 80  80  80
          ^   ^    ^
  red amount  |    |-----green amount
              |---------------- blue amount
```

Numbers with a high red amount are very red, (like `#990000` or `#ff0000`) numbers with a high blue amount are very blue (`#00ff00`), etc...

If the amount of red, green, and blue are all the same, then the color will look grey.  So, all of the following colors will be grey-ish

```
#757575
#343434
#a3a3a3
```

Because I copied the same 2 numbers over and over.  In the first one, the red amount is the same as the blue amount is the same as the green amount, which is **75**.

Now how do you get this into your code?  Generate 2 random letters to get the first color, and then add that to the end of your string 2 more times.

### Edit 2

Let's talk about the code in "The Low Flying Pelican"'s answer really quick.

The first line will construct an **array** with letters from "A" to "F" in it.  This means that our resulting color will only have letters in its hex code from "A" to "F".  If we want other digits, we need to add them to the start of this string.  Because we are picking numbers randomly, the order of digits in this string does not matter.

The 4th and 5th lines (`var digit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);`) pick an INDEX into this array.  Pretty much it works like this.  If our array has the elements `A, B, C, D, E, F`, then the **0th** one is `A`, the **1st** one is `B`, and so on.  This means that if we do

```
    letters[0]
```

We will get `A`, and if we do

```
    letters[1]
```

We will get `B`.

We want to do

```
    letters[<some random number>]
```

Which gives us a surprise letter between A and F.  We do this twice to get two surprise letters, like `EB` or `CC`.  In the given code it works like this:

```
    //Pick 2 random numbers between 0 and 5.
    //Math.floor() rounds the random numbers down, so instead of 
    //getting 3.42123, we just get 3.  This is necessary because 
    //we can't take the 3.4th element of our array!
    var digit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var digit2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
```

Later you see this code

```
    letters[digit1]
```

which fetches the letter associated with the random number named "digit1"

If we are only picking random letters between A and F, we can't get the full range of greyscale.  For that we need to pick random numbers from 0 to F.  To do this, we need to add `"0123...89"` to the start of the array in the given code, AND we need to change the code so it picks a number between 0 and 15, instead of 0 and 5.

Comment: Should I get the Html code for it or the RGB numbers?

Comment: Either one will work for finding the pattern I'm thinking of.  Keep messing around with the website until you find it.

Comment: Honestly for the project I am doing #9BABB0 Would work fine.

Comment: It would be a little difficult for a simple program to generate a color like that randomly.  Go further to the left.  In fact, go all the way to the left side.

Comment: So how would this too? Going all the way to the left is only providing me with different tones of white grey and black #ABABAB

Comment: I thought you were looking for different tones of white, grey and black?

Comment: I am looking to limit the color spectrum that the getRandomColor function produces

Comment: Yes.  According to your question, you want "it to be more White & Grey colors".  Do you want greyscale?  Or do you want to keep some color?

Comment: I can keep some color. I should have phrased it better

Comment: I see.  Do you *need* to keep some color?  The pattern to keep zero color is more straightforward than the patter to keep a little color.  (also, do you see the pattern that generates 100% greyscale yet?)

Comment: Let's go with entirely greyscale.  Here are the hex codes for 4 colors that are entirely greyscale: {#acacac, #848484, #474747, #fefefe}.  Does that help?

Comment: Not entirely because I am unsure where to plug that in. That has been my problem I am not sure where to enter that

Comment: Well, so what do you think the pattern is?

Comment: Maybe I am just missing something simple but when I place it in the variable color it does not work

Comment: You wrote this function (right?), and you want to change it so it only picks from a limited number of colors.  All of the colors you want to pick from have one key thing in common.  If you can figure out what that thing is, you can change the function that you wrote to give only colors you want.

Comment: i am really unsure. I am trying several things. None of them seem to be working

Comment: I did not write the function, It is from a project that I found online that happened to work when I added it with my code

Comment: I am guessing what all the colors I want to pick from have in common is that they are greyscale?

Comment: @JonyTalassazan ohhh.  If you didn't write this yourself, please say so.  Low Flying Pelican's code will certainly work fine for what you need.  If it's not giving dark enough colors, change `"ABCDEF"` to `"0123456879ABCDEF"` and the  `* 6` to ` * 16`   If you want the code to be explained to you, a forum or chat room would be a better place for that.

Comment: Thank you! It all pieced together in my head

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me.  Too bad we are not on a more chat-friendly site, or I could walk you through the code.

Comment: So what exactly does the 0123456789 do? Why does it affect it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the points yet to chat. I would love to ask you some other questions

Comment: Bravo! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

White/Gray colors do have all components the same, so,

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = "ABCDEF".split("");
    var color = "#";

    var digit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var digit2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        color += letters[digit1];
        color += letters[digit2];
    }
    return color;
}
```

change to use only ABCDEF values so that it would be more towards white and gray, also to make sure all 3 components are the same